# Align text by string using shell commands

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, printf

Say I've got some text in a file like this:

```
lorem ipsum asdf gh 12345
hello, world! asdf gh this is a test
ee asdf gh ii
```

Notice that each line contains "asdf gh". I'd like to be able to use some shell command(s) to align that text based on that delimiter string, so I could do:

```
$ cat my-file | some-command
lorem ipsum     asdf gh   12345
hello, world!   asdf gh   this is a test
ee              asdf gh   ii
```

In this example I added extra spaces around the delimiter, but it doesn't really matter either way. That is, the output could just as well be:

```
$ cat my-file | some-command
lorem ipsum   asdf gh 12345
hello, world! asdf gh this is a test
ee            asdf gh ii
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I know `column` can columnate things, but it can only use whitespace or characters (not strings or patterns) as delimiters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

awk is a better tool for formatting output:

```
awk -F 'asdf gh' '{printf "%-15s%-10s%-10s\n", $1, FS, $2}'  file
lorem ipsum    asdf gh    12345    
hello, world!  asdf gh    this is a test
ee             asdf gh    ii
```

You can change numbers in `printf` for more customization.

Answer (score 3):

Using printf function in awk

```
awk '{printf "%-20s%s\t%s\n",$1,FS,$2}' FS="asdf gh" file

lorem ipsum         asdf gh  12345
hello, world!       asdf gh  this is a test
ee                  asdf gh  ii
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use awk and have two problems, you could do along the lines of:

```
sed 's/asdf gh/%&/g' <my-file | column -t -s'%'
```

assuming that '%' is a valid separator that doesn't otherwise appear in your text.